# AngularJS: function call when closing modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I imagine this is quite a simple answer, but I can't find the right syntax.

I have my modal opening like so,

```
$scope.assignment = function (groupId) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'assignment_form',
        controller: 'GroupsAssignmentController',
        windowClass: 'modal-user-window',
        resolve: {
            id: function () {
                return groupId;
            }
        }
    });
```

All I want to do is have a function run when the modal is closed so my main screen is updated.

I'm not sure if this involves $modal.close?

```
    $modal.close({
    //getAllGroups();
    });
```

Comment: $modal.open(modalOptions).result.finally(function(){
  console.log('modal has closed');
});

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
modalInstance.result.finally(function(){ 
    // do your work here
});
```

You can also use then

```
then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)
```

SuccessCallback is excetuted when the promise is resolved. errorCallback is executed when the promise is rejected. Finally notifyCallback is executed when notified.

In the case of angular-ui's modal, clicking on the backdrop will result in a rejected promise. With this in mind, your code could be changed to :

```
modalInstance.result.then(function () {
  alert('Modal success');
}, function () {
  alert('Modal dismissed');
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, just a quick follow up question. How do i actually return from a modal to have it register as a success? At the moment I am closing my models when the user clicks a button with $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'). Can't seem to get it to execute the success part.

Comment: Yes that is by design. It will execute the errorCallback function - in above code, alert('Modal dismissed')  will be called

Comment: Yeah I understand why that is happening, but what do I change when closing the modal so that it will execute the success part? Can't seem to find an answer on google. Is there a different method to dismiss I should be using?

Comment: Well, I really don't think that is possible. On dismiss modal your errorCallback is executed. You need to code it there.

Comment: But there must be something you can put in your modal to make it execute the successCallback? I don't need to use dismiss.

Comment: OK, i figured it out. You need to use $modalInstance.close() to activate the successcallback and dismiss for the error one as I was doing.

Comment: @user3407039 - great!!